# Iterating through a series to find values >= x then use values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, iteration, series

I have a series (of length 201) created from reading a .xlsx spread sheet, as follows:

```
xl = pandas.ExcelFile(file)
data = xl.parse('Sheet1')
data.columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
A = data.a
```

So I am working with A and if I `print (A)` I get

```
0      76.0
1      190.0
2      0.0
3      86.0
4      0.0

196    156.0
197    0.0
198    0.0
199    320.0
200    0.0
Name: Vazi, Length: 201, dtype: float64
```

I want to iterate through A and find all the values => 180 and make a new array (or series) where for the values in A => 180 I subtract 180 but for values in A =< 180 I use the original value. I have tried the following but I get errors:

```
nx = len(A)
for i in range (nx):
    if A_new(i) >= A(i) + 180:
        else A_new(i) == A(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) / [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
new_s = s.mask(s.ge(180),s.sub(180))
#new_s = s.sub(180).where(s.ge(180),s) #or series.where
```

or [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
new_s = pd.Series(data = np.where(s.ge(180),s.sub(180),s),
                  index = s.index,
                  name = s.name)
```

---

We could also use [`Series.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html)

```
new_s = s.copy()
new_s.loc[s.ge(180)] =s.sub(180)
```

---

**new_s output**

```
0       76.0
1       10.0
2        0.0
3       86.0
4        0.0
196    156.0
197      0.0
198      0.0
199    140.0
200      0.0
Name: Vazi, Length: 201, dtype: float64
```